# Cannot do nested pattern matching

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

condition is a `Seq[Expression]`

```
val (subqueryPredicates, nonSubqueryPredicates) = condition.partition(
      _ match {
        case _: InSubquery => true
        case _: Not(child: InSubquery) => true
        case _ => false
      }
    )
```

Compiler continues complains Type mismatch, expected Expression => Boolean, actually Expression => anyVal

The problem here is the `Not(child: Subquery)`,as long as I remove (child: Subquery), the complaint would stop.

I have no idea why nested pattern match cannot perform here. Below is the definition of `Not`

```
case class Not(child: Expression)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern should be either

```
case _: Not =>
```

or

```
case Not(child: InSubquery) =>
```

Former is so called *type pattern* and type is `Not`, not `Not(child: InSubquery)`.